# How to set the default selected value for a Doctrine ObjectRadio element

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I've got a simple user registration form where a user can choose their own user type. The user type maps to a role. This is part of a zf2 application using the doctrine2 module.

The relevant part of the init() method of my user fieldset looks like this:
    public function init()
    {
        // ... other field definitions ...

```
    $roleRadio = new ObjectRadio('role');
    $roleRadio->setLabel('What type of user are you?')
              ->setOptions(
                    array(
                        'object_manager' => $this->objectManager,
                        'target_class'   => 'MyUser\Entity\Role',
                        'property'       => 'roleId',
                        'is_method'      => true,
                        'find_method'    => array(
                            'name'   => 'findBy',
                            'params' => array(
                                'criteria' => array('userselectable' => true),
                                'orderBy'  => array('displayorder' => 'ASC'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    )
    );

    $this->add($roleRadio);

    // ... more stuff ...
}
```

I'm using Doctrine's ObjectRadio class for this element to automatically populate the value options. Is there any way to set the default selected value?
I know I can just do something like this:

```
$form->get('user')->get('role')->setValue(3);
```

But I don't want to hard code this and I also don't want to put that kind of logic in my controller.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what do you mean by "I don't want to hard code this", but you can do it as you said in your controller, or you can do it in the form definition by setting attributes as the following:

```
$roleRadio->setAttributes(array('value' => 3));
```

Comment: What I meant by hard coding is referring to the id of the default option. I don't want it to break if the id of the role changes, since it's just an auto-increment column.

Comment: If you have the role object then you can set `ObjectRadio` current value using `setValue($roleObject)`, and you can add unique role_code column to roles table and select role by its code... this will remove the dependency on ID

Comment: Yes that's how I solved it now. I added a configuration option for the user module 'default_role' which refers to the unique role name. In the UserService I now have a getDefaultRole() which returns the Role entity. I assign that to the form when the form is being created. Thanks for chipping in.